# How to return an object from a Parse query?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

This is how I'm doing it:

```
  const Document = Parse.Object.extend('Document')
  const query = new Parse.Query(Document)
  let result = {}
  query.get(id, {
    success: function (object) {
      result = object.toJSON()
      console.log(result)
    },
    error: function (object, error) {
      alert(`Error: ${error.code} ${error.message}`)
    }
  })
  console.log(result)
  return result
```

The first `console.log(result)` outputs the object:

> Object {content: "trstrtrts", createdAt: "2016-01-17T11:20:30.694Z",
>   title: "Document 2", updatedAt: "2016-01-17T11:20:30.694Z", wordCount:
>   "3000"…}

But the second one returns nothing. What's the correct way of returning an object from a Parse query?

**EDIT:**

Based on Anon's answer I tried this:

**store.js:**

```
store.first = (id) => {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Document)
  return query.get(id)
}

export default store
```

**main.js:**

```
store.first(to.params.id).then((document) => {
   console.log(document.toJSON())
   return document.toJSON()
 })
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function ParsePromise() {
>   _classCallCheck(this, ParsePromise); this._resolved = false; this._rejected = false; this._resolvedCallbacks = [];
>   this._rejectedCallbacks = []; } has no method 'all'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second

```
 console.log(result)
```

take place before the first one.Query is an async operation.
The correct way of doing this is to use promises. For example you can do

```
function foo(id){
     var Document = Parse.Object.extend('Document');
     var query = new Parse.Query(Document);
      return query.get(id);
}
```

and then use the function foo like this:

```
foo(objectID).then(function(object){
  //do something with the object.

})
```

---

here is an example to  show the async in js.

```
     console.log('a');
     setTimeOut(function(){console.log('b')},0);
     console.log('c');
```

the order of the printing is 
      a
      c
      b

(we have time out 0 but the function of the timeout goes in the event loop and take place after the function done)

for more information you can read https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop
about the eventloop

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I get a type error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object function ParsePromise() {
    _classCallCheck(this, ParsePromise);

    this._resolved = false;
    this._rejected = false;
    this._resolvedCallbacks = [];
    this._rejectedCallbacks = [];
  } has no method 'all'`

Comment: it should work maybe the problem with the const .. try use var to check

Comment: same problem. Maybe because I have to set the `resolve` and `reject` callbacks?

Comment: No. this not resole/reject. I am going to check it

Comment: Oh I forget foo().then I worte foo.then. You have to write foo().then()

Comment: I did `foo().then`. Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100888/discussion-between-alon-and-alexchenco).

Comment: I use the `get()` method. `first` is just the name of the method I created.

Comment: the only thing that I can think about is that you use ()=> syntax 
cause it changes the reference of  this.What heppands if you change this to function() .. syntax
I dont know this should work..